# Looking for a radio-transparent epoxy/resin

Tags: home-experiment

I have much hobby experience with 2-part resins, but this time I'm looking to
make a repair part for the inside of a microwave oven (everything I've tried so far heats up, but the original part does not).  I need the result to be hard enough (shore durometer D ~ 75) to rotate the glass turntable tray within the oven, withstand ~ 250 degrees Fahrenheit (it will not be in contact with food) and be radio-transparent at the frequency of 2.4 GHz.

I've reached out to over a dozen epoxy/resin manufacturers, but am having trouble finding such a product.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be able to find a home-usable [thermosetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosetting_polymer) resins such as epoxy or RTV silicone rubber that meets your needs: low dielectric loss (dissipation factor), moderate hardness and stability at microwave cooking temperatures.

[Bakelite](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/bakelite) (urea-formaldehyde thermosetting resin) *might* be usable, as it's hard and temperature resistant, though its dissipation factor is ~0.005, a tiny bit higher than ideal. However, one-off molding of Bakelite is non trivial, requiring pressurized and temperature controlled molds.

A table of [electrical properties of some plastics](https://www.professionalplastics.com/professionalplastics/ElectricalPropertiesofPlastics.pdf) shows polystyrene, polypropylene and some fluorinated plastics such as polytetrafluoroethylene with dissipation factors <0.001, but these are less hard than Bakelite.

[Glass-filled plastics](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/df45/7c024d56006fe7badb0446940e3db1b3398e.pdf) such as glass-epoxy laminate (printed circuit board, PCB, material) and [RO4000® hydrocarbon ceramic laminates](https://www.rogerscorp.com/acs/products/54/RO4003C-Laminates.aspx) might be better choices. However, instead of casting a part, you'd need to machine the part from one or more PCB's laminated together. This might actually be easier, for a one-off part, than casting.

Comment: He needs a plastic that won't absorb the microwaves emitted within a convention microwave oven.

Comment: @MaxW, that's what the dissipation factor shows The lower the factor, the less absorbed. That said, the factors are usually given for 1 MHz, rather than 2.4 GHz, but the glass-filled PCB material cited is ~0.003 at *10* GHz.

Comment: @DrMoishe_Pippik Thank you for your answer.  The FR4 approach is interesting!  I wonder what modern microwave oven turntable tray couplers are made of.  (I don't know whether one can tell by looking at it in the oven under the glass tray.)

Comment: @DrMoishe_Pippik If you're still around, I have a side question: How would one laminate/glue PCBs together; wouldn't I have the same heating problem since the glue is not microwave transparent?

Comment: Possibly, but the amount of energy absorbed depends on the geometry and size of the material. You could use a non-carbon based cement, such as a ceramic cement. See http://www.sauereisen.com/wp-content/uploads/HIGHTEMP.pdf